# java.net.BindException in Spring

Tags: spring, hapi

I am getting java.net.BindException. I am using Spring to autowire all beans, so I don't think two threads of the same process are running. Also I use different ports for all the processes.

What could be the possible cause of this error? Is there any way to check the cause?

```
11:13:48,350  WARN [pool-2-thread-3] Service:215 - Thread exiting main loop due to exception:
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.AcceptorThread.afterStartup(AcceptorThread.java:106)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.concurrent.Service.run(Service.java:202)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at ca.uhn.hl7v2.app.AcceptorThread.afterStartup(AcceptorThread.java:103)
```

Edit: I got the source of the error. I am using a Spring `@Component` which implements `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`. This component runs on tomcat startup, but when I run the unit tests, it runs the Component again. Why is that happening?

Here is the component for reference -

```
@Component
public class RunBackgroundServices implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private final BackgroundServices backgroundServices;

    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Autowired
    public RunBackgroundServices(BackgroundServices backgroundServices) {
        this.backgroundServices= backgroundServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(backgroundServices);
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
        executor.shutdown();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the port that you´re using?. Looks like you block that port and you dont release it.

Try this.

```
     Linux: netstat -lpn | grep "your port" Then with the pid. kill -9 pid

     Mac: lsof -i tcp:"your port" Then with the pid. kill -9 pid
```